# how to combine two reports using salesforce report api

Tags: api, reporting

How can we create a single report of two unrelated objects using report api?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't allow to combine two unrelated objects either from UI or through API for reporting purpose.

Even if in Joined report works on the relations.

> A joined report can contain data from multiple standard or custom report types. You can add report types to a joined report if they have relationships with the same object or objects. For example, if you have a joined report that contains the Opportunities report type, you can add the Cases report type as well because both have a relationship with the Accounts object

You can create a single report freshly and try to implement those logic (filter or field display or grouping) into new report.